# Error message on radio button reference when upgraded to Excel 16

Tags: excel, vba

Hello everyone and thank you for your time and support,

My company just upgraded our excel to Excel 365 and now the sheet which I had with some radio buttons will not work and produce the below error:

[image]

It was working perfectly before, the error happens on the first line of code below, the three form control radio buttons are in a groupbox, any tips or advice will be highly appreciated.

```
    Sub Approved_Click()

    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Yearly").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Scroll Bar 10").Visible = False
```

Comment: Are your radio buttons Form controls, or ActiveX controls?

Comment: `...ActiveSheet.Shape..` Maybe the active sheet is not the one you think is active? Try and use proper references for example `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YouSheetName").Shapes("Yearly")....`

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not answer my question about the control type, please try the next code:

```
Sub testOptionButtons()
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 'for a Form Type use this code:
 Debug.Print sh.Shapes("Yearly").ControlFormat.value
  'for a ActiveX Type use this code:
 Debug.Print sh.Shapes("Yearly").OLEFormat.Object.Object.value
End Sub
```

Or, test both of them if you are not sure about their type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer, the problem seems to be that every time the form control scrollbar gets hidden, it is getting DELETED somehow, I'm never searching to see why Excel 2016 is doing this.

Comment: It seems Excel 2016 has some problems with form controls, in the end I just had to remove all of them to avoid all the errors, thank you all again